# dynamically adding button based on my label text database column in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a rails app, in which I want to add buttons dynamically based on my label text in the database.I have a questionnaire schema and it contains label column with various kind of label i.e, `PERSONAL STYLE`,`STYLING`,`WARDROBE`. My UI should automatically add buttons for each label column value i.e. if it contains 3 label in label column then it should add dynamically 3 buttons with `PERSONAL STYLE`,`STYLING`,`WARDROBE` written on it. And on clicking those button , these label specific question must show in UI.

Here is the image for the UI
 [User Interface(UI) for above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bsR9.png)

My schema is like this with 3 columns. Questionnaire Model which has questionnaire table with these schema
       `id , label , question`

When i click on `STYLING` button, `STYLING` labeled questions from database should show in UI.
How to achieve that.
Currently I am able to load all questions from database.But I have to now show label specific questions on the UI on clicking the label buttons.

here my html.erb code

```
<% @questionnaire.each do |question| %>
<label> <%= question.label %></label>
<h2> <%= question.text %></h2>
<% end %>
```

code in controller

```
 @questionnaire = Questionnaire.all
```

Every suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it for viewing purpose only, like toggle button ?

Comment: No it’s a functionality, you should check the image which i attached

Answer (score 0):

This might have syntax errors, but I think the idea is clear.

*Add two classes to each question. "labels" and the specific label:*

```
<% @questionnaire.each do |question| %>
  <div class="labels <%= question.label %>">
    <label> <%= question.label %></label>
    <h2> <%= question.text %></h2>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*Add a link for each different label. You should show these links to the right of your page (this is not included in this example).*

```
<% @questionnaire.uniq { |question| question.label }.each do |question|
  <%= link_to question.label, '#', class: "set-label" %>
<% end %>
```

*Add a script to handle clicks on these links:*

```
<script>
  $(".set-label").on("click", function () {
    lab = $(this).text()     // get the label that was clicked
    $(".labels").hide()      // hide all questions
    $(".labels."+lab).show() // show questions with this label
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: how to get the label that was clicked, lab = $(this).text  is not working @Pablo

Comment: Sorry. It's .text()